# How to install Fabric and Crashlytics

Tags: swift, facebook, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I'm Swift developer. And I have a problem about Fabric and Crashlytics.
In my project I used Facebook Frameworks but not from CocoaPods.
During the developing, I need to use Fabric an Crashlytics. So I use it from CocoaPods and followed description in www.fabric.io.
But when I imported Fabric and Crashlytics, there was an error that compiler can't find Fabric & Crashlytics framework.
So I copied these framework to framework directory or enter these path into search path item in build setting.
After that the error disappeared but other error occurred. Other error is compiler can't find FBSDKCoreKit.
How can I solve this problem.
Help me!
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have Fabric and Crashlytics in projects that include the FB SDK and it works well. You were right to install Fabric and Crashlytics through CocoaPods, did you forget to open the `.xcworkspace` instead of the `.xcodeproj` after installing the pods? Also, cleaning the project (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) and the build folder (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) and closing/reopening the project may help.

Manually copying the frameworks in not the best idea as you will stop receiving updates via `pod update`.

Comment: But it doesn't work. I always work with .xcworkspace

Answer (score 2):

add fabric in info.plist.then clean project and run it. i hope it's working for you!.